# Sequelize Node.js - Nested Objects

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to achieve the following output in my sequelize Node.js query:

```
[{ user: "test", reactions: [...], count: 5 }, { user: "test2", reactions: [...], count: 3 }]
```

Used the following query:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  db.Reaction.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      visualizationId,
      scope,
      score
    }
  })
```

It returns me the count among all records including the reactions model.
But what I need is to have a count of reactions grouped by userId and linked to the result the reactions given by that userId.

Do you have some idea how I can accomplish this by taking in account the desired output?

Thanks and regards,
Patric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Reactions.findAll** and then group user reactions in memory using something like the **groupBy** method from the **lodash** lib.

```
const reactions = await db.Reaction.findAll({
    where: {
      visualizationId,
      scope,
      score
    }
  })
const groupedRections = groupBy(reactions, x => x.user)

return Object.keys(groupedRections).map(x => ({
  user: x,
  reactions: groupedRections[x],
  count: groupedRections[x].length
}))
```

Comment: Thanks Anatoly that seems a much easier way to go, as currently I used  a raw query from sequelize to return me the total count of reactions per user including all the reactons for that user, and then used some array manipulations technique to put it in my desired output.